# To prove that $p$ is a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I'm reading a book about proofs and fundamentals on my own and, currently, I'm having trouble proving this result.

**Theorem:** *Let $p$ be a positive integer bigger than or equal to $2$ and such that, for any integers $a$ and $b$, if $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$. Show that $p$ is a prime number.*

**Sketch Work:** My work so long has been assuming that $p$, in this condition, is a composite number. Hence, there exists some integers $m$ and $n$, such that $p = mn$ and $1 < m,n < p$. If $p|ab$, then there is some integer $k$ such that $kp = ab$. How do I show from here that $p$ will not divide $a$ and $b$ and hence we have a contradiction?

Is my strategy good? What should be the next step? Thank you!

Comment: So does $p$ divide $mn$?

Comment: p is defined to be equal to some $mn$ since we are assuming that is a composite number @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes in fact $p$ will divide $mn$

Comment: Good. So what can you conclude?

Comment: Since both $m$ and $n$ are less than $p$, p does not divide $m$ and $n$, which is a contradiction because we are assuming that if our number $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $b$ for any $a$ and $b$ integers. Hence we have a contradiction. Therefore, $p$ in this conditions must be a prime number! Is this correct? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p$ is composite, then $p=mn$ where $1<m,n<p.$ We have $p \mid mn,$ so by assumption $p\mid m$ or $p \mid n$ which is a contradiction since $m,n<p.$

**Edit:** The hypothesis says that **if** $p \mid ab,$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b.$ In order to use this, you need to find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p \mid ab.$ The hypothesis **does not** say that there definitely exist such integers. Assuming that the conclusion does not hold **guarantees** such existence and then puts you in a position where you can use the hypothesis.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that, I was so focused in my sketch that I miss that important detail! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Andrew I hope my edit highlights your error.

Comment: So, as you said, we are assuming that the conclusion does not hold but our number $p$ is such that have the property described in our hypothesis. By showing that this fails with our hypothesis (because we can find such integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p$ dives $ab$ but $p$ does not divide $a$ and $b$), hence we have a contradiction, so $p$ will be a prime number. Is that it? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I reallly appreciate it :)